# Error while creating "Promoted Links" list in SharePoint via Web Service

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-webservice

I'm trying to created list "Promoted links", templated id - 170, but getting error that list template is invalid.
Is there any way to create this list ?
The sharepoint is SharepointOnline and I'm using addList method on List web service (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.addlist%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
listsSoap.addList("Test list", "Test list", 170);
```

Thanks

Comment: what is your sharepoint version and how do you try to create this library? some code?

Comment: Hi, Sorry I forgot to mention: The sharepoint is SharepointOnline and I'm using addList method on List web service (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.addlist%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). And I'm creating many other lists using this method without any problem, but this list is somehow fail :         
     listsSoap.addList("Test list", "Test list", 170);

Comment: i see, but documentation does not state that it is possible to use this template id =170 with this method. Look at avaible id table. For this list you need to use something else. JSOM or REST.

Comment: The documentation says only about very limited list of templates that can be used, but it works with much more. So, I don't think it's a method limitation and if REST is works than SOAP should work also.